# How does parquet encryption work in AWS EMR?

Tags: hive, parquet, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-kms

I'm looking at the AWS documentation for [enabling encryption on EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-data-encryption-options.html), but I can't find any information on how this impacts the performance of Parquet files. Can EMR still take advantage of Parquet when optimizing queries?

Examples:

```
select count(1) from my_table
```

Would only scan the metadata in the parquet file and wouldn't require downloading the entire file.

```
select column from my_table
```

Would only fetch data for that particular column.

How is this possible when the files are encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you can refer to this Uber Eng Blog which talks about the deployment of Parquet Encryption at a large scale. https://www.uber.com/blog/one-stone-three-birds-finer-grained-encryption-apache-parquet/

For the Metadata question, you can read https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Encryption.md. Basically, if you have permission, then it is transparent to your query.